# unit testing __init_subclass__ method in python 3.x

Tags: python, testing, inheritance, definition

I am trying to unit test an inherited class for which its base class implements  `__init_subclass__` method. Code is the following:

##### **`quick_test.py`**

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import create_autospec

class Parent():

    PROPERTY = NotImplemented

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        if cls.PROPERTY is NotImplemented:
            raise NotImplementedError("Please implement the `PROPERTY`.")
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

    def __init__(self, connection_type="default"):
        self.connection_type = connection_type


class Child(Parent):

    PROPERTY = "has value"


class ChildNoProp(Parent):
    pass


class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_required_params(self):
        mock = create_autospec(Child)
        self.assertRaises(NotImplementedError, mock)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The problem is I can't even reach the test case because `ChildNoProp` definition calls `__init_subclass__` in base class and raises exception.

Is there a way I can unit test this with current implementation, or should I scrap the error raising in `__init_subclass__`?

Comment: Put the definition of `ChildNoProp` inside the test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the class inside the `assertRaises` block.

```
with self.assertRaises(NotImplementedError):
    class ChildNoProp(Parent):
        pass
```

If the `class` declaration inside of a method makes you uncomfortable, you can use the `type` constructor directly.

```
with self.assertRaises(NotImplementedError):
    type("ChildNoProp", (Parent,), {})
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like python is very neat as they say. This goes to my cheat sheet!